# How to store a C++ variable as a value in NSDictionary?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

I'm coding in Objective-C++ and would like to translate a ObjC struct into C++.
The ObjC-side variables are in `const NSString*` , 
the C++-side variables are in enum.

My project uses ARC.

I'm doing it this way:

```
NSDictionary* myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: My::NameSpace::enumVar, MyObjCVar, nil]
```

This gives me a compiler error:

```
Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC.
```

Is there a generic way to store any C++ type into NSDictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
NSDictionary* myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSNumber numberWithInt:My::NameSpace::enumVar], MyObjCVar, nil];
```

but why not use the more modern syntax?

```
NSDictionary* myDict = @{MyObjCVar : @(My::NameSpace::enumVar)};
```

I very much prefer the second option.

Comment: You kids with your fancy modern syntax...get off my lawn!

Comment: @Lance Didn't know about this modern syntax. Thanks for the tip! Much much more succinct.

Comment: where is key here?

Comment: and what about `setObject` - `[dicts setObject: C++Object?  forKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];`

Answer (score 2):

you can't directly store anything but `NSObject` pointers (`id` type) inside `NSDictionary` for either the key or value. You either need to box the object/pointer/value in an objective c object such as `NSValue` or `NSNumber`, or use [NSMapTable](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSMapTable_class/Reference/NSMapTable.html).

Answer (score 1):

Since the keys of the dictionary must be objects, and the value you are currently using is an `int`, you should be able to convert it to an `NSNumber` object:

`[NSNumber numberWithInt:enumVal];`